# Plot word association network with python

Tags: python, networking, text, associations, mining

I am developing a program that turns plain text into a coocurrence network. My final output so far are coocurrence weights in the form of a library from which I can draw the values for the associated keys:

```
{('space', 'galaxy'): 0.312, ('sun', 'galaxy'): 0.209, ('sun', 'space'): 0.121}
```

and single word frequencies to set the blob size. I have seen exactly what I want to do with python done with R [here on the example of the word fat, cat and the](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7wxMZ.png)

Is it possible to do something like that in python? I am using python 3.7 in pycharm(Anaconda)
I read something about a coocurrence matrix but I am not sure how that helps me visualizing the data with such a network.
thanks for any help or suggestions.

Comment: look into the library `networkx` if you're set on a graph representation. Although something like a  simple heatmap might also work. In the future, please limit SO posts to issues with specific software issues  :)

Comment: I don't think that there is something off with the OP's post. The goal of SO is to help programmers like us solve whatever issues they currently face. As long as the problem is clear and a solution is available, then you shouldn't impose limits like this. And how can a simple heatmap solve his problem?

Comment: @jcoderepo, being organized and helping others aren't mutually exclusive. The fact of the matter is that SO has [explicit rules](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) (#4) against questions that seek library recommendations or how-to's. I'm not being dismissive of OP -that's why I suggested libraries. And a heatmap is just an adjacency matrix with weights as color intensity. As you can imagine, you can form a complete graph with your nodes and send weights to the heatmap values.

Comment: Thank you for the help. I did't mean to violate rules. I think the differentiation between solving an issue and seeking a guide is very spurious for a beginner like me. The more I progress, the more specific and issue focused the questions will become.